# MPMediaPlayerController how to play repeat audio

Tags: ios, mpmusicplayercontroller

How to play **repeat , shuffle** with **`MPMusicPlayerController`** ?

I have already set

```
[player setRepeatMode:MPMusicRepeatModeDefault];
```

Comment: why don't u try AVAudioPlayer?

Comment: http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/mediaplayer/reference/MPMusicPlayerController_ClassReference/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/c/tdef/MPMusicShuffleMode

Comment: http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/mediaplayer/reference/MPMusicPlayerController_ClassReference/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/c/tdef/MPMusicRepeatMode

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are several [repeatModes](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/mediaplayer/reference/MPMusicPlayerController_ClassReference/Reference/Reference.html) like

```
MPMusicRepeatModeOne, MPMusicRepeatModeAll
```

So instead of setting it to `MPMusicRepeatModeDefault` set it to other mode as you want. (See reference link for more ...).

Also, there are several [shuffleModes](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/mediaplayer/reference/MPMusicPlayerController_ClassReference/Reference/Reference.html) like

```
 MPMusicShuffleModeOff, MPMusicShuffleModeSongs, MPMusicShuffleModeAlbums
```

In both - repeatMode and shuffleMode, the `default` mode indicates you not set them explicitly. So set them to other modes as you want.